# Setting Selected Color of JColorChooser

Tags: java, jcolorchooser

IS it possible to set the selected color of the JColorChooser?

I tried

```
_ColorChooser_Color.setColor(color);
```

but it doesn't work. Meaning, it compiles and runs, but doesnt change the actual selection of the component.

I am now trying to do something like this

```
 _ColorChooser_Color.setSelectionModel(new ColorSelectionModel().setSelectedColor(color));
```

But this is giving me an error - `ColorSelectionModel is abstract; cannot be instantiated`

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What happens? What is supposed to happen? Are there any errors? Note: variable names in Java are supposed to be like `colorChooserColor` - no underscores, the first letter is lowercase.

Comment: Is there a legitimate reason to not have underscores. I understand that there are proper naming conventions, but I never heard of having underscores causing problems. I named all my GUI components with underscores first then the component type, then the var name for easier reading. As for it doesnt work part, it compiles, but doesnt actually change the selection of the component. updated my question

Comment: `I understand that there are proper naming conventions` - then use them, especially if you want people to read your code. The forum highlights code based on the standards, which makes it easier for us to read the code. `but doesnt actually change the selection of the component.` - what component. The color chooser or some other component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
colorSelector.getSelectionModel().setSelectedColor(newColor)
```

Doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/colorchooser/ColorSelectionModel.html

Comment: Tried this but it was unsuccessful in selecting the color.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that if you are working with the tables then you can do the thing as

```
Color color = JcolorChooser.showDialog(Component,title,initialColor);
```

this will return the color of the color chooser to you and you can do whatever you want with the color